# Does opencv3 support measurementMatrix attribute for kalman filter?

Tags: 16.04, python-2.7, opencv

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, python 2.7.12 and I have installed opencv 2.4.9.1 version. I am trying to run a code for kalman filter and I get the following error: 
AttributeError: 'cv2.KalmanFilter' object has no attribute 'measurementMatrix'
Do I have to install opencv3 in order to use measurementMatrix, transitionMatrix and processNoiseCov attributes? If not, any other possible solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to this:https://medium.com/@debugvn/installing-opencv-3-3-0-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-7db376f93961
I've installed a version of opencv3 (3.4.3) with: pip install --user opencv-contrib-python and it worked. It looks like the previous version of opencv I had installed didn't support these attributes of kalman filter.